# Get-Content returning a System.Object[] instead of System.String in a Windows 7 environment

Tags: .net, powershell

I have a script I wrote in a Windows 10 environment with .Net 4.7.03056 installed that works without issues. However, when it is instead run in a separate Windows 7 environment (not sure what version of .Net installed) the script encounters a MethodNotFound exception:

Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'IndexOf'

Here's the code that is resulting in the issue:

```
$Result = Get-Content $LogDirectory\java_output.txt
$MCPindex = $Result.IndexOf('MCP devices:')
```

And the contents of the java_output.txt are expected to be:

```
Serial number [Description] [ID]
FTDI devices:
MCP devices:
0001234567 [MCP2200 USB Serial Port Emulator Microchip Technology Inc.] [id=0]
```

When run in Windows 10, and pipe $Result to get-member, the datatype is System.String, which does contain the IndexOf method, hence no issues.

When run in the Windows 7 environment, the exception message being thrown instead indicates that $Result is a System.Object[]. I don't currently have direct access the this environment to troubleshoot, so I'm at a loss currently as to a likely suspect for this behavior. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PowerShell v2** (which Windows 7 originally shipped with) **doesn't expose the `.IndexOf()` method on arrays**, such as on the `[object[]]` (`System.Object[]`) arrays that you get when you capture multiple lines from a file read with `Get-Content` in a variable.

The reason is that **`.IndexOf()` isn't a *direct* method of an array, but provided via the implementation of the `System.Collections.IList` *interface***, and **it is only in PSv3+ that *interface* methods are also surfaced in PowerShell**.

---

The most concise - but non-obvious - workaround is to use *reflection* in PSv2:

```
$MCPIndex = [Collections.IList].GetMethod('IndexOf').Invoke($Result, 'MCP devices:')
```